# Why does not subequations numbering work as intended when I customize it?

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, numbering, mathtools, subequations

I am using `IEEEtran` for typesetting and it seems that subequations are cited appropriately when leaving their numbering to the default value. When I customize it, however, the equation numbering resets to 1 for all subequations, but when I reference them, they are referenced correctly.

[image]

Here is my source code:

```
\documentclass[]{IEEEtran}

    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}
    \usepackage[]{mathtools}

        % Custom equation numbering for journals

            % Numbering style
            \newtagform{Eq}[\renewcommand{\theequation}{[\arabic{equation}]}]{}{}
            \usetagform{Eq}

            % Referencing style
            \renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}


    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \patchcmd{\subequations}{\alph{equation}}{-\Roman{equation}}{}{}



\begin{document}



\begin{equation}
    P =
    \begin{dcases}
    %
    E = m c^2 & c \approx 3.00\times 10^{8}\,\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}
    \\
    \int x-3\, dx & \text{display style}
    %
    \end{dcases}
    %
    \label{eq:Eq1}
\end{equation}


\begin{subequations}


    \begin{align}
        I_{sc} & = I_{sc,ref} & \hspace{-15mm} \bigg[  1 + \frac{\alpha}{100} (T_{op}-T_{ref}) \biggl]
        \vspace{2 mm}
        \label{eq:SubEq1}
        \\
        %
        V_{oc} & = V_{oc,ref} & \hspace{-15mm} \bigg[  1 + \frac{\beta}{100} (T_{op}-T_{ref}) \biggl]
        \vspace{2 mm}
        \label{eq:SubEq2}
        \\
        %
        P_{mp} & = P_{mp,ref} & \hspace{-15mm} \bigg[  1 + \frac{\gamma}{100} (T_{op}-T_{ref}) \biggl]
        \label{eq:SubEq3}
    \end{align}


\end{subequations}

See SubEq. \ref{eq:SubEq1}


\begin{equation}
    P =
    \begin{dcases}
    %
    E = m c^2 & c \approx 3.00\times 10^{8}\,\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}
    \\
    \int x-3\, dx & \text{display style}
    %
    \end{dcases}
    %
    \label{eq:Eq4}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

As an aside, is there a way to customize subequations numbering without using `\patchcmd` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify (and simplify) the `\newtagform` instruction.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{etoolbox, calc, siunitx}

% Custom equation numbering for journals
\newtagform{Eq}{[}{]}
\usetagform{Eq}
\patchcmd{\subequations}{\alph{equation}}{-\Roman{equation}}{}{}
%% or, possibly:
%% \patchcmd{\subequations}{\alph{equation}}{-\arabic{equation}}{}{}

% utility macro
\newcommand\spbox[2]{\makebox[\widthof{$#1$}][r]{$#2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    P =
    \begin{dcases}
    %
    E = m c^2 & c \approx \SI{3.00e8}{\meter\per\second}
    \\
    \int x-3\, dx & \text{display style}
    %
    \end{dcases}
    %
    \label{eq:Eq1}
\end{equation}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
    I_{\textrm{sc}} &= \spbox{P_{\textrm{mp,ref}}}{I_{\textrm{sc,ref}}}
    \Bigl[ 1 + \frac{\alpha}{100} (T_{\textrm{op}}-T_{\textrm{ref}}) \Bigr]
    \label{eq:SubEq1}
    \\[2mm]
    %
    V_{\textrm{oc}} &= \spbox{P_{\textrm{mp,ref}}}{V_{\textrm{oc,ref}}}
    \Bigl[ 1 + \frac{\beta}{100}  (T_{\textrm{op}}-T_{\textrm{ref}}) \Bigr]
    \label{eq:SubEq2}
    \\[2mm]
    %
    P_{\textrm{mp}} &= P_{\textrm{mp,ref}} 
    \Bigl[ 1 + \frac{\gamma}{100} (T_{\textrm{op}}-T_{\textrm{ref}}) \Bigr]
    \label{eq:SubEq3}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
See subeq.~\eqref{eq:SubEq1}.

\begin{equation}
    P =
    \begin{dcases}
    %
    E = m c^2 & c \approx \SI{3.00e8}{\meter\per\second}
    \\
    \int x-3\, dx & \text{display style}
    %
    \end{dcases}
    %
    \label{eq:Eq4}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up comment, about *why* it's necessary to use `\patchcmd` to achieve the OP's formatting objective and, relatedly, *why* there is no counter called `subequation` (or `subequations`).

I'm not in a position to address the deep, philosopical *why* questions directly. (For one, I was never involved in the design of the `amsmath` package!) However, I can provide an explanation of *what* the `subequations` environment does. This explanation will, hopefully, address your why questions indirectly.

Let's begin by looking at the relevant code in the file `amsmath.sty`:

```
\newcounter{parentequation}% Counter for ``parent equation''.
% ...
\newenvironment{subequations}{%
  \refstepcounter{equation}%
  \protected@edef\theparentequation{\theequation}%
  \setcounter{parentequation}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{0}%
  \def\theequation{\theparentequation\alph{equation}}%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{parentequation}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
```

- A new counter *is* defined, but it's called `parentequation` rather than `subequation`.
- `\subequations` (equivalent to `\begin{subequations}`) executes the six lines of code that end with `\ignorespaces`.
- When `\subequations` is run, the `equation` counter is stepped (via `\refstepcounter`). Next, the value of `equation` is assigned to the `parentequation` counter. E.g., if the value of the `equation` counter was "15" after being stepped, the value of `parentequation` is set to "15".

  The instruction `\protected@edef\theparentequation{\theequation}` takes care of the possibility that the author may need to cross-reference the group of (sub)equations as a whole. A call-out to the "parent equation" will use the format that's used for "normal" equations in other parts of the document.
- Next, the `equation` counter is reset to `0` and the `\theequation` macro -- the macro that is used to display the counter -- is (re)defined as a composite of the `parentequation` and `equation` counters. Importantly, this redefinition of the `\theequation` macro is local to the `subequations` environment: it will cease to be in effect once the `subequations` environment ends.
- After all this, the body of the `subequations` environment is entered. In this part, one usually finds environments such as `equation`, `align`, etc. As part of their work, these environments usually step the `equation` counter.

  The beauty (genius?!) of the `subequations` setup now becomes apparent: the subordinated `equation`, `align`, etc environments need not be informed at all that they are embedded in a `subequations` environment. Hence, the subordinated environments can keep doing their usual stuff, and they don't have to switch from stepping the `equation` counter to stepping the (non-existent) `subequation` counter. (And, they don't have to be informed when the `subequations` environment ends!)
- When the `subequations` environment ends, the instructions `\setcounter{equation}{\value{parentequation}}` and `\ignorespacesafterend` are run.  `\setcounter{equation}{\value{parentequation}}` serves to reset the value of the `equation` counter, to the value of `parentequation`. E.g., if the value of `parentequation` was "15", this value is transferred (back) to the `equation` counter.

To recap, the `subequations` environment does not require the subordinated `equation`-type environments (`equation`, `align`, etc) to do anything different from what they would do if they were not inside a `subequations` environment.

I'm not in a position to decide whether the simplicity of this setup was *the* reason for why it was chosen. Nevertheless, I think it's worth being aware of.

Speaking for myself, using `\patchcmd` to modify the innards of the `subequations` environment doesn't seem like a high price to pay for this simplicity. For sure, I wouldn't agree with the proposition that there's an issue with consistency (or inconsistency, as the case may be) in one's operations.

Comment: It works. Thank you :) But is there a way to modify subequations numbering without `\patchcmd` command?

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh - Is there a reason for *not* using `\patchcmd`? BTW, I used the command mainly because you used it in your code.

Comment: I customize floats and main equations without having to patch anything. It is a matter of consistency. Table counters, for example, are `\thetable` and main equations counters are `\theequation`, so why do not the subequations have a counter named `\thesubequation`?

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh - I've provided an addendum to describe and discuss the setup of the `subequations` environment. The discussion, hopefully, also explains why your preferred modus operandi, *viz.*, modify a counter called `subequation`, cannot be made to work. If you're worried that the "patch" in `\patchcmd` somehow implies that it does something half-baked, or "patchy", please rest assured that using `\patchcmd` is not, in any way at all, inferior.